# map externailzed strings android

Tags: android, string, dictionary

I use an independent library to perform an action in Android. In case of error the library throws an exception with an integer parseble string error code in it (like `"233"`). There are several error codes. I would like to create a properties file to map error messages to error codes.

This would be easy, but the value of IDs of the externalized strings (like `R.string.divisionError =  2130968584`) can be regenerated in whichever build, so they are not stable, the value can be changed.

I can not write to that property file stg like this:

```
233=2130968584
```

I could put

```
233=divisionError
```

and then use reflection to look for a field called `divisionError` in R.string.class, get its value and retrieve the string using `getString(int)`.

Isn't there a better way?

Comment: My first question is, what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Why can you not just use R.string.divisionError?  Add it to your map with something like `map.put("233", R.string.divisionError)`.

Comment: That is what I did for first, but I would like to separate the mapping from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `android.content.res.Resources` class has a method `getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)` that you can use to get the numeric resource id when you know its name.

So you can put the resource name into your property file and then use this method to get the id.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will do so.